# Updates to JsPdf libary in exporting tables

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have the code below am using to export a table to pdf. Although am changing the margins in the jspdf code, the output does not have margins set. It seems the output does not match with the specifications in the code. Are there any changes i can make or alternatives to be able to change margins?

report.js

```
const exportPDF = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF('px', 'pt', 'a4');
  const margins = {
    top: 40,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 20,
    right: 20,
  };
  autoTable(doc, {
    html: '#idi',
    margin: margins,
    didDrawPage: function (data) {
      doc.setFontSize(8);
      doc.setTextColor(0);
      const header = 'Your Table Header';
      const headerWidth = doc.getStringUnitWidth(header) * doc.internal.getFontSize() / 
      doc.internal.scaleFactor;
      const pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
      const textWidth = headerWidth > pageWidth ? pageWidth : headerWidth;
      doc.text(header, margins.left + ((pageWidth - textWidth) / 2), 20);
    },
  });    
  doc.save('report.pdf');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the code on a repo of mine with a table and changed the margins:

```
const handleOnExportClick = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF("px", "pt", "a4");
    const margins = {
        top: 100,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 60,
        right: 60,
    };
    autoTable(doc, {
        html: "#idi",
        margin: margins,
        didDrawPage: function (data) {
            doc.setFontSize(8);
            doc.setTextColor(0);
            const header = "Your Table Header";
            const headerWidth =
                (doc.getStringUnitWidth(header) *
                    doc.internal.getFontSize()) /
                doc.internal.scaleFactor;
            const pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
            const textWidth =
                headerWidth > pageWidth ? pageWidth : headerWidth;
            doc.text(
                header,
                margins.left + (pageWidth - textWidth) / 2,
                100
            );
        },
    });
    doc.save("report.pdf");
};
```

I received this result:

[image: Screnshot of pdf with changed margins]

I think the problem do not comes from the provided code snippet.